# Variable and method naming conventions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm aware there's a Rails naming convention for variables and methods to be written like `this_is_my_variable` and `this_is_my_method`.

However, I'm currently seeing more often a more Python and Objective C approach using like `thisIsMyVariable` or `thisIsMyMethod`, also I think the code looks prettier this way.

My question is this Python-style naming convention also acceptable on Rails as a maybe more refreshed naming approach or should I strictly stick to current Rails naming convention?

Comment: you should stick with the ruby/rails convention of naming variables.  the reason for this is if you intend to use any modules... the modules will use this_convention so you don't want to mix and match.

Answer (score 5):

I guess that would depend who you're asking. As far as I know, there are no official ruby style guidelines, but basically everyone uses `snake_case` for variable and method names, `CamelCase` for classes and modules, and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for other constants.

A bit of googling gave me [this question about ruby style guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616037/ruby-coding-style-guidelines), which lists a whole bunch of links to different (unofficial) style guides.

My personal opinion is that `mixedCase` is just confusing and looks out-of-place in ruby. I have seen it, but I always have to do at least a double-take in order to actually be able to read it (and make sure that I'm not actually reading Java code).

To be all honest, I would use `snake_case` in method and variable names in Python as well (which seems to be compliant with [PEP8 - Naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)), and only ever use `mixedCase` in Java or JavaScript.

Back to you question though. I know people that would accept `mixedCase` in ruby code, but most ruby devs I know definitely would not, and some would probably scream about it and throw things at you.

Comment: Just a note: there exists a [Ruby Styleguide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) on GitHub, which lists exactly your naming rules as the normal ones.